# Moving objects causes jitters

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I created a simple level with in the scene itself.

Now I want to scroll this level from right to left , but while moving the objects which composes the levels begin to jitter.

I tried following ways to move the level .Some begin to work perfectly in unity player but none of them worked smoothly in iOS simulator :-

Case a) Tile map created in the hierarchy does not have any rigidbody attached.

a.1] moved by changing position directly :

`transform.position -= scrollLeftBy * Time.deltaTime;` -> lots of jerk

a.2] moved using :

`transform.Translate(newVector3(m_Velocity*Time.deltaTime,0,0));` -> no jerk in unity player , but still jerks in iOS simulator.

Case b) Added rigidbody to the layer , `isKinemtic=true`. `Velocity iteration = 8` and `Position iteration = 3`

b.1] inside FixedUpdate / Update , moved using velocity ,

`transform.rigidbody2D.velocity = m_Velocity;` :- > jerks in Unity Player , as well as iOS Sim

b.2] 
inside FixedUpdate / Update , moved using ,

`transform.rigidbody2D.transform.position -= scrollLeftBy;` :-> No jerks in Unity Player but jerks in iOS Sim.

The level created have following hierarchy :-

TileMap->Layer0->Chunk( Contains a number of tiles and renders all of them as a single mesh.)

I attached rigidbody2D and scrolling script to the this chunk.

what I may be missing ?

EDIT:

- Please find video [here](http://tinypic.com/r/28v3a5g/8).Running on device
- Tried on Device also , it still jitters.
- I also tried Interpolate ,Extrapolate and None , for Interpolate option but still jitters!

Comment: Have you tried on an actual device? I know that when I've tried using the emulator the performance is less than good!

Comment: yes ! on Device also it jitters..

Comment: What FPS is on your device?

Comment: @SergeyKrusch I am getting 30fps consistently on iPad mini

Comment: Not so high, you know... It's kind of guessing without seeing what exactly is going on on your device/simulator (can you FRAPS your game in simulator?). But I would say that the problem is in relatively low FPS.

Comment: please find video [here](http://tinypic.com/r/28v3a5g/8). Running on device